# Vectors with determinants

Tags: determinant

> If $\begin{vmatrix} a & a^2 & 1+a^3 \\ b & b^2 & 1+b^3 \\ c & c^2 & 1+c^3 \end{vmatrix}=0$ and vectors $(1,a,a^2)$, $(1,b,b^2)$ and $(1,c,c^2)$ are non-coplanar, then the product $abc$ equals

In this I could not understand what is the use that the vectors are coplanar .

Can any body provide me a hint .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint tells us that $\begin{vmatrix} 1 & a & a^2 \\ 1 & b & b^2 \\ 1 & c & c^2 \end{vmatrix}\neq0$.

To use this hint, note that
$$0 = \begin{vmatrix} a & a^2 & 1+a^3 \\ b & b^2 & 1+b^3 \\ c & c^2 & 1+c^3 \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} a & a^2 & 1 \\ b & b^2 & 1 \\ c & c^2 & 1 \end{vmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix} a & a^2 & a^3 \\ b & b^2 & b^3 \\ c & c^2 & c^3 \end{vmatrix}= \begin{vmatrix} a & a^2 & 1 \\ b & b^2 & 1 \\ c & c^2 & 1 \end{vmatrix} + abc\begin{vmatrix} 1 & a & a^2 \\ 1 & b & b^2 \\ 1 & c & c^2 \end{vmatrix}.$$

Switch some columns in the first matrix, and you'll have a common factor that you can factor out and that you know to be nonzero.